# Bot only plays music for a few seconds then it doesn't play anymore even there's no error

Tags: discord.js, distube

[still online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ9Qr.png)

[after 34 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7jUH.png)

package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.7.0",
    "@discordjs/voice": "^0.8.0",
    "@distube/soundcloud": "^1.1.0",
    "@distube/spotify": "^1.2.1",
    "@distube/yt-dlp": "^0.0.2",
    "@distube/ytdl-core": "^4.11.10",
    "@sapphire/utilities": "^3.11.2",
    "ascii-table": "^0.0.9",
    "discord.js": "^13.15.1",
    "distube": "^3.3.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.1",
    "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.9",
  },
```

distube-handler:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
  client.distube = new DisTube(client, {
    emitNewSongOnly: true,
    emitAddSongWhenCreatingQueue: false,
    emitAddListWhenCreatingQueue: false,
    leaveOnEmpty: true,
    leaveOnFinish: false,
    leaveOnStop: false,
    youtubeDL: false,
    updateYouTubeDL: true,
    emptyCooldown: 60,
    savePreviousSongs: true,
    ytdlOptions: {
      highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024 * 64,
      quality: 'high',
      format: 'audioonly',
      liveBuffer: 60000,
      dlChunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 64
    },
    plugins: [
      new SpotifyPlugin({
        emitEventsAfterFetching: true
      }),
      new SoundCloudPlugin(),
      new YtDlpPlugin()
    ]
  })
```

i installed and tried all versions of distube, but it still only plays music for a few seconds and doesn't play anymore

Comment: try updating to the latest discord.js/voice `npm i @discordjs/voice@latest`